# Why is my "current time" in Cakephp incorrect, is this a framework bug?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have a cakephp application, and in the add.ctp view there is a date-time field with the cakephp default as current time (I didn't decide this), and I realised that the default time is wrong. It defaulted to 12:43:15 AM when the time was in fact 12:43:15 PM. I waited till 01:00:03 PM and the time was correct again, without any changes made.

[image: Cakephp bug?]

(The server is 9 minutes ahead)

Here is the code that creates the form:

```
    <h2><?php __('Assign tasks');?></h2>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Task');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php __('Ticket: '.$ticketName); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('Tasktemplate.id');
        echo $this->Form->input('Task.queue_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('Task.user_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('Task.due_date')
    ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
```

And the model, controller & view is basic as I created them with the framework (baked), with only cosmetic changes to the view.

Is this a cakephp bug? Can someone send me a link to where I can post bugs for cakephp?

Comment: The CakePHP bug tracker is at http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com

Comment: @Juhana : Thanks. Took me a while to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a bug, where the AM drop down updates only after 1 PM instead of 12 PM.
The bug tracker is at cakephp.lighthouseapp.com .